# Redirect in Reactjs with React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect to home page after i clicked on a button in login page..But when i clicked the button in address bar ,home page's path is shown( it redirects to the home page)..but it doesn't render the component relevant to that path.It still shows the login page with home page address.So,i have to refresh the page to render the home page.what is wrong here???

In my login page...this is the function i used for the button onClick..

```js
gotopage()
  {
        this.props.history.push('/home')
   }
```

In my index,js page..

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Redirect ,browserHistory} from "react-router-dom"; 
import { Firstpage } from "./Firstpage";
import { Login } from "./Login";
import { Home } from "./Home";
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history=createBrowserHistory();


    class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
    return(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
         <div>
        <switch>
        <Route path="/"   component={Firstpage} exact> </Route>
        <Route path="/home"   component={Home}> </Route>
        <Route path="/login"  render={(props) => <Login {...props} history= 
         {history} } />}> </Route>
         </switch>
         </div>
     </Router>
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Pls add the route specifications

Comment: add the router config.

Comment: and add the component which should navigate to home page

Comment: react router version you are using

Comment: version is 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I would suggest. Since you are using React router 4.x
BrowserRouter has no history prop as per documentation remove that. 
Update your code to following and see if it works.

Change switch to Switch and I can't see it being imported from react-router.
use withRouter from react-router in your Login component.

```
export default withRouter(Login)
```

Update the main route config as followed.

```
     <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/"   component={Firstpage} exact> </Route>
            <Route path="/home"   component={Home}> </Route>
            <Route path="/login"  render={(props) => <Login {...props}/>}> </Route>
        </Switch>
     </Router>
```

Read more about withRouter, BrowserRouter here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter.

On more details take a look at the following post 
https://medium.com/@AkyunaAkish/understanding-react-router-4-df73a66d96c4

Comment: How can i use this to redirect..??Can u explain more???                                                                           
    export default withRouter(Login)

Comment: Yes it will pass history as prop to Login component. Then you can do history.push and it should work try once.

Comment: @Sandz happy to help.